# Win32:Does ImageList_ReplaceIcon failed with unproper ImageList_Create

Tags: c++, winapi, c++14, visual-studio-2019

As the title says, I'm trying to write a simple window program, but when I try to change the icon of my TreeView, it goes wrong. I'm pretty sure my icon was loaded because I did this:

```
HICON hIcon;
//hinst is my global variable
hIcon = LoadIcon(hinst,(char*)IDI_ICON_MAIN);
if (hIcon == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "LoadIcon failed", "error", MB_OK);
}
```

It works fine then I use `ImageList_ReplaceIcon()`:

```
if (ImageList_ReplaceIcon(iml, 3, hIcon) == -1)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "replace icon failed", "error", MB_OK);
}
TreeView_SetImageList(hwndTV, iml, TVSIL_STATE);
```

First, I thought, maybe it's because I gave the wrong `ILC_COLOR` in `ImageList_Create()`, then I rechecked the bit of my icon then reset the parameter, but it's still not working.

Can anyone give me some clue of what is wrong? I already checked with Google and read the docs mutiple times, perhaps I missed something?

**UPDATE** [2022/05/31]

Here is my TreeView:

[image: TreeView]

I'm tring to change my icon to the red circle.

Comment: `GetLastError` should return an error with indications as to what the problem is.

Comment: I thought the GetLastError can only be used when api mentioned it,but thanks I will try it

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I got operation succeed in my error message,but how is that possible if my ImageList_ReplaceIcon returns -1 to me,I think the operation succeed might be the message from other functions

Comment: Actually, it looks like you are correct: `ImageList_ReplaceIcon` does not appear to set the last error variable. Sorry to have mislead you.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it's fine I'm still trying to look some clue of it to see which part I might missed,anyway thanks for giving advice :)

Comment: @Alex Please explain what exactly is going wrong. What does the icon look like? What does the TreeView look like when the icon is not displayed correctly? Can you provide a [mcve]? There is nkt enough detail provided to help you.

Comment: Does your imagelist have at least 3 items in it?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hi,I updated my image on the post, there is my treeview and it always looks like that,when I'm trying to replace my icon

Comment: @JonathanPotter No,there's no icon in it at first,does it needs at least three items in it? I didn't see it requires neither in ImageList_AddIcon nor ImageList_ReplaceIcon

Comment: @JonathanPotter I changed my code and I found that I need to AddIcon first, so that I can ReplaceIcon.

Comment: I can see my icon now, just a small mistake and I update the conclusion on my post thanks for helping.

Comment: @Alex Your 2nd update should be posted as an answer instead of an Edit. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for let me knowing that, I posted the answer under the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see my icon now, thanks. I appreciate those who gave me advice.

ReplaceIcon() can only be used when I have already added an icon into it. If there's no icon in it then the only condition I can use is to set the index to -1, so that the ReplaceIcon() can add the icon for me.